# CSS Animations change mid-animation

Tags: html, css, sass, css-animations

I'm practicing CSS animations by making a loading spinner. It's just 4 boxes moving in and out of view. I have it working as intended in VS Code when I just run the .html file. However, when I tried it in an actual angular project with a large data pull, the animation will mess up mid way through.

Posted below is the "blue box", which grows to the right, scaleY toward the bottom, and scaleX toward the left. All the boxes do this same thing, just in different directions with different delays, so there are a total of 16 keyframes in the file. The first loop is usually fine, however, on the second or third, the transform origin of this blue box and another gray box will switch, so the blue box will grow to the left, and the gray box to the right (when it's supposed to be going left). And then the transform origin of the scaleX and scaleY will randomly switch as well (this happens on Firefox, on Chrome or Edge, the animation will just freeze).

I don't get it, is it too much processing power when combined with the data pull?

```
  .boxes .blue-box {
    width: $box-width;
    height: $box-height;
    position: absolute;
    background: blue;
    left: $blue-left;
    top: $blue-top;
    transform: scaleX(0) translateZ(0);
    opacity: 0;
    transform-origin: left;
    animation: moveBlue $animation-length infinite;
    border: 3px solid rgb(0, 0, 180);
  }
  @keyframes moveBlue {
    13% {
      transform: scaleX(1);
      opacity: 1;
      animation-timing-function: ease-out;
      transform-origin: left;
    }
    51% {
      transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(1);
      transform-origin: bottom;
    }
    63% {
      transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(0.1);
      transform-origin: bottom right;
      opacity: 1;
    }
    75% {
      transform: scaleX(0) scaleY(0.1);
      transform-origin: bottom right;
      animation-timing-function: ease-out;
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
```

Comment: If you keep the animation running after your "data pull" is complete, do you still experience the issue? It's probably not an issue with the animation if the above code works locally. That means it has something to do with your angular project. We can't really diagnose it without more information.

Comment: Yes, the problem continued after the data pull (A hefty API call) was completed

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful when to display the loader and when to remove it.  I have added an example below. call the loader when you are getting results from the api and before you display the results, make suer you clear the loader. In so doing, the loader will not be affected midway data pull.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Joel, I'll give this a shot later today and let you know how it works out